# How am i suppose to use my List Java in other method

Tags: java

Hello can someone explain why i cant use "moviesList" in other method?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Parser {

    private Movies mov;

    public Parser(){
    }

    public void mapperParser() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        List<Movies> moviesList = mapper.readValue(new File("Movies.json"),new TypeReference<List<Movies>>() {});

        Comparator<Movies> cmp = Comparator.comparing(Movies::getName);
        moviesList.sort(cmp);

        Comparator<Movies> cmp1 = Comparator.comparingInt(Movies::getAge);
        moviesList.sort(cmp1);

        Comparator<Movies> cmp2 = Comparator.comparing(Movies::getDirector);
        moviesList.sort(cmp2);
    }

    public void hashMapParser{
        Map<Movies, Movies> moviesHashMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < movieslist.size(); i++){
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add all values from `moviesList` to `hashMap` by algorithm but i cant use `moviesList` for some reason
How should i change my code?

Comment: Did you mean to make it an instance variable? Right now, it's a local variable.

Comment: It's scoped within your method. You may want to go through a tutorial on understanding scopes

Comment: Yes i want to make it an instance variable how can i do it?

Comment: See the answer from Jhanzaib Humayun

Comment: Sorting it one way, and then sorting it a different way, seems sort (haha) of pointless.  Don't you want to do something with the results of the first two sorts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, the variable `movieList` only exists inside the `mapperParser()` method. So, its not accessible outside that method. If you want to use it elsewhere, add another class variable like this:

```
public class Parser {

    private Movies mov;

    private List<Movies> moviesList; // here is the variable

    public Parser(){
    }

    public void mapperParser() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        this.moviesList = mapper.readValue(new File("Movies.json"),new TypeReference<List<Movies>>() {});

        Comparator<Movies> cmp = Comparator.comparing(Movies::getName);
        moviesList.sort(cmp);

        Comparator<Movies> cmp1 = Comparator.comparingInt(Movies::getAge);
        moviesList.sort(cmp1);

        Comparator<Movies> cmp2 = Comparator.comparing(Movies::getDirector);
        moviesList.sort(cmp2);
    }

    public void hashMapParser{
        Map<Movies, Movies> moviesHashMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.moviesList.size(); i++){
            //do stuff here
        }    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`moviesList` is a local variable that is only accessible from the `mapperParser()` method. You probably want to make it a field like `mov`, something like this:

```
public class Parser {

    private Movies mov;
    private List<Movies> moviesList; 

    ...

    public void mapperParser() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ...
        moviesList = mapper.readValue(new File("Movies.json"),new TypeReference<List<Movies>>() {});
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The field will be accessible from `hashMapParser()`.

Another point: Java is case-sensitive, the `l` in `moveslist` should be an `L`.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the List inside a method, it's only visible inside that method.

If you want other methods in this class to access the List, instead define it in your class just like you have with "private Movies mov"

You can use your class constructor to initialize it.

Comment: This answer would be improved with a demonstration. As is, it reads more like a comment.